# Many time series in the same table: how to generate JSON string in correct format

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, django-orm

I have simple time series stored in a Postgres database, that I can load into a Pandas dataframe.

```
date    number      system_id
1       33.1        1
2       24.2        1
3       14.1        1
4       15.5        1
[...]   1113        1
1       4513        2
2       53.4        2
3       24.8        2
4       13.12       2
[...]   3333        2
```

The wanted result is a JSON string that I can feed to my JavaScript charting, that looks like this:

```
[

[1, number in date 1(of system_id 1), number in date 1(of system_id 2), number in date 1(of system_id 3), ...],
[2, number 2(of system_id 1), number 2(of system_id 2), number 2(of system_id 3), ...],
[3, number 3(of system_id 1), number 3(of system_id 2), number 3(of system_id 3), ...],
[4, number 4(of system_id 1), number 4(of system_id 2), number 4(of system_id 3), ...],
[...]

]
```

I can pull the above table directly in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Or I can pass it to `pandas.DataFrame()` in Python using Django-ORM.

Wether I obtain the desired result with the ORM, with Pandas or directly in SQL is the same, it just needs to be the fastest possible, which is what made me start to search for a solution in SQL.

However, I don't see how. What I need is to `GROUP BY date` and then create a different column for each different `system_id`: is this even possible or advisable?

`GROUP BY date` asks me to provide an aggregation function (`sum`, `avg`...) for the `number` column. Is there an aggregation function that performs what I'm trying to do?

Comment: not sure what you're doing with the number column, I assume `sum`? something like: `df.groupby(['date','system_id'])['number'].sum().unstack()`

Comment: No, not sum. Nothing: I need that to remain unchanged. `[[1, 33.1, 4513], [2, 24.2, 53.4], ecc]`

Comment: The numbers in the data example are completely random.

Comment: `df.groupby('date')['number'].apply((lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))).reset_index().values.tolist()` closest I can get - but it changes the numbers into strings which might break your javascript visualisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.4.2.2.17.1.1) on Postgres or [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on MySQL.

The output would be something like

```
| date | numbers       |
|------|---------------|
| 1    | 33.1,4513,... |
| 2    | 24.2,53.4,... |
| 3    | 14.1,24.8,... |
```

And the query

```
SELECT date, STRING_AGG(number) numbers 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do this with a bit of help with the pandas crosstab function,

my assumptions here are that you need the number columns as ints as opposed to strings (as in my comments solution)

if there are any strings in the date column it will be registered as an object, thus read as a string.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipbard(sep='\s+')
print(df)
    date    number  system_id
0   1   33.10   1
1   2   24.20   1
2   3   14.10   1
3   4   15.50   1
4   [...]   1113.00     1
5   1   4513.00     2
6   2   53.40   2
7   3   24.80   2
8   4   13.12   2
9   [...]   3333.00     2
```

we can then pass this into a crosstab whilst passing the `system_id` in the columns argument

```
js_object = (pd.crosstab(df.date, df.system_id, 
values=df.number,aggfunc='first').reset_index().values.tolist())
print(js_object)
 [['1', 33.1, 4513.0],
 ['2', 24.2, 53.4],
 ['3', 14.1, 24.8],
 ['4', 15.5, 13.12],
 ['[...]', 1113.0, 3333.0]]
```

hope that helps!